# Time complexity for modification on quicksort

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures, time-complexity, quicksort

Let a function named QUARTERSORT which gets an array and sort it in the following way:

- If `n`<100` it uses the regular QUICKSORT
- Otherwise, we split the array to on `A1 = A[1,...,n/4]` and `A2 = A[(n/4)+1,...,n]`.
- Then, we call QUARTERSORT twice: `B1 = QUARTERSORT(A1)` and `B2 = QUARTERSORT(A2)`.
- Finally, we merge `B1` and `B2`.

Now, why is the recurrence `T(n) = T(0.25n) + T(0.75n) + O(n)` and not `T(n) = T(0.25n) + T(0.75n) + O(nlogn)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intuitively, you can ignore the part about quicksort, because it only happens for small `n`, and the big-O notation only talks about values of `n` that are "big enough". So the parts of the algorithm are:

1. Recursive invocation on 1/4 of input: `T(1/4 * n)`
2. Recursive invocation on 3/4 of input: `T(3/4 * n)`
3. Merging: `O(n)`

A bit more formally: time complexity of quicksort is `O(1)`. This addition can be safely ignored, because there are larger parts in the time complexity, like `O(n)`.

Comment: Thank you. By the way, what's the solution for this recurrence? My guess is O(nlogn), but how can one show it?

Comment: Just plug the recurrence into itself until all the numbers become 1 (or any other constant). There also is [Master theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem), but I am not sure it's applicable here. Update: just looked at the article in Wikipedia; it contains a link to a more general "Akra–Bazzi method", which will certainly work in this case.

Answer (score 1):

The recurrence is `T(n) = T(0.25n) + T(0.75n) + O(n)`, because every step of the algorithm by its own is `O(n)`. Splitting the array to 2 parts is `O(n)`, and merging the two parts is `O(n)`, so each step by its own is `O(n)`, which gives us total of `T(n) = T(0.25n) + T(0.75n) + O(n)` as expected.

Comment: Thank you. By the way, what's the solution for this recurrence? My guess is O(nlogn), but how can one show it?

Answer (score 1):

Quick Sort takes `O(n)` to find the pivot. Once the pivot is found, it remains unchanged.

The size of 2 subproblems are O(N/4) and O(3N/4), so the recurrence is

`T(n) = T(0.25n) + T(0.75n) + O(n)`

Comment: Thank you. By the way, what's the solution for this recurrence? My guess is O(nlogn), but how can one show it?